# Cassels' algorithm vs. “divided cells” algorithm 

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Cassels' algorithm mentioned in [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22777/how-to-find-a-closest-integer-point-to-intersection-of-two-lines) looks similar to Delone's “divided cells” algorithm. Are there any differences in these algorithms?

Comment: The question is motivated by Robby McKilliam's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22777/ where he attributes an algorithm to Cassels.